# What to use for a simple HTML5 game playable on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

At work, I am developing this "mystery"-type (2D) game where users go around rooms/location, tap on objects (objects/items/people) and get some form of feedback like a message, a chat (think RPG chat) or finding some item.

**Technology used currently**

Currently its developed using pure HTML/CSS, where everything is a div. Animations uses CSS3 Animations or jQuery ones depending on suitability. Chats implemented using simple buttons (on click, depending on reply do something). There is panning of the game stage involved - the viewable area is smaller than the actual game stage. So users will drag the stage around by tapping and drag.

**The problem**

*Details here are not really important ... you may want to just scan through this section if you prefer*

The most problematic part with this is **performance**. On a mobile device, its terribly jerky for a simple 2D game like this. Taps are not really responsive, sometimes requires more taps to register. We already tried to use CSS animations and transforms where possible.

The 2nd problem is **debugging**. Since this game is played on the client's app, which embeds own game in an in app browser/webview. Debugging is made more complicated (no Chrome usb/remote debugging, currently we use Firebug Lite - which is a pain and lacking in features ...). Performance also suffers further. There seem to be weird bugs also like jQuery animation callbacks running at the wrong time. Views scrolling unexpectedly. Sometimes the tap area of the objects are off the actual object - when the user pans the stage, the graphics move as expected, but the tap area is off the object - eg. tapping on the right of an object triggers it, but not tapping on the object (this happens on some devices of a particular brand)

**Any recommendations?**

For such a type of game, is a game engine suitable? Which one? Most I see are more for more complex games and maybe overkill to include.

Might using HTML5 canvas solve my graphical performance issues? Another game was developed using ImpactJS, its of a different kind, and the performance is considered ok. But with this chat and tap (to interact) based game, I wonder if such a large framework is actually required.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the taps is that phones handle clicks different than touches: for each click there is a delay (300ms, if I'm not mistaken) during which it waits to see if the user performs a double-click. That's usually where most of the sluggishness on the mobile devices comes from.

You never described which part exactly is causing the game to perform badly. If you have tons of elements on screen, each with their own CSS (and especially CSS like shadows, animations...) it will likely slow your game down.

Using canvas (and dropping jQuery to squeeze out maximum performance from the app) might be a good idea here. Without any huge frameworks/engines. Using canvas will also help you with the issues you described under debugging - while you won't be able to inspect every element on canvas, things like displaced objects/click areas won't be happening as everything (except chat - I strongly suggest you don't render text on canvas because it's very slow) is located in a single element and all the layering will happen on the canvas itself, not CSS.

But don't forget: while a well-designed canvas app might definitely outperform what you currently have, it can also perform worse if done badly.

Comment: I am using fastClick so I think the 300ms delay should be fixed. Regarding part of app causing problem. Its abit hard to say ... on a desktop browser it works ok ... mobile less ok the main problem is when the game is played from the client's app, which is possibly an Android WebView. I think there are afew comtributing factors... some not so optimized/legacy code like jQuery animations and others triggering reflows etc. There is likely quite alot so its hard to pinpoint which is contributing a larger part to the problem. About the wierd tap areas ... its really hard to determine